# Website Localisation (or Localization)

Tags: css, html, localization, web

I've been looking into localising my website lately and coming up a bit blank with Google searches. I keep finding how to localise apps  but not website or GeoLocation which is a bit too specific.

I'm looking to be able to localise using pure HTML(5) and CSS(3) mainly. I'd like to be able to localise sections in a page rather than having separate URLs for each country.

Any help with this would be really useful so thanks in advance.

EDIT: Any example for server side, js or other languages would be useful if there isn't a pure pure HTML(5) or CSS(3) way of doing this.

Comment: Most solutions are purely server side. And most client side solutions are very light and prone to be very dependent on the problem (my most usual solution is a few lines of js). That's probably why you didn't find anything.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Could you give a js example?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is one I use in an ajax application with almost no html (everything is generated from the data client side).

The first part ensures you can specify the language in the url  (by adding `&lang=it` for example) and that it is stored in local storage (permanent user preferences in the browser) :

```
myapp.available_langs = ['en', 'fr', 'it']; // the first one is the default language
// Exemples :
//   {en:'hi', fr:'Bonjour'}
//   {fr:'Bonjour'}
myapp.loc = function(map) {
    if (map[myapp.lang]) return map[myapp.lang];
    for (var i=0; i<myapp.available_langs.length; i++) {
        if (map[myapp.available_langs[i]]) return map[myapp.available_langs[i]];
    }
    return "-label not found-";
};

myapp.getUrlParameter = function(name, defaultValue) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var results = new RegExp( "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)" )
         .exec( document.location.href );
    if( results == null ) return defaultValue;
    else return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);
};

myapp = {};
myapp.lang = localStorage['lang'] = myapp.getUrlParameter('lang', localStorage['lang']||myapp.available_langs[0]);
```

And it is used like this at some other place :

```
$('body').append('<div product id=product_header>\
    ...
        <tr>\
            <td> '+myapp.loc({en:'cut',fr:'date'})+': <span id=product_cutdate>?</span></td>\
            <td> '+myapp.loc({en:'grade',fr:'qualité'})+': <span id=product_grade>?</span></td>\
            <td> '+myapp.loc({en:'length',fr:'longueur'})+': <span id=product_length>?</span> m</td>\
            <td> '+myapp.loc({en:'thickness',fr:'épaisseur'})+': <span id=product_thickness>?</span> mm</td>\
            <td> '+myapp.loc({en:'width',fr:'largeur'})+': <span id=product_width>?</span> m</td>\
        </tr>\
```

You might choose to use also the user agent but in real corporate use I find it about useless. Note that i18n solutions can be very various. I don't advocate to use this, this is simply a pattern I like. Many people prefer to extract the strings in external properties files but in my experience it leads to more bad translations and is harder to manage (as long as only one team speak all the involved languages and that you don't have 10 of them).

Comment: The biggest issue with this approach is that this file is neither translation nor translator friendly. You won't be able to load this up to translation tool for processing. For a small app, maybe, but for an entire website this would be very hard to manage.

Comment: @eakkas I suppose that by translator you mean any kind of tool enabling the translation of resources files. Then yes. But honestly, did you ever see a localization correctly done without developers having to adapt it to the application by looking in the code (and sometimes change it) ? In my opinion the total separation of development, localization and internationalization is mostly a myth. But I won't pretend this approach is general, hence the precautions in my comments and in my answer.

Comment: All I am trying to say that the format of this file will be hard to manage in multiple languages for high volume text.

Comment: @eakkas I agree. As soon as you have more than 2 or 3 languages and your web application is mostly text, it's clear you need to do the translation server-side anyway, in order to avoid sending too much useless data on the network.